# getJSON and android browsers

Tags: android, jquery, getjson

I'm trying to do a simple JSON request the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script>
  (function(){
    $.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function (data) {
     alert(data.host)
     });
   })();
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This works fine on desktop chrome and other browsers, now I've tried using jquery mobile and tried all browsers on my phone, it used to work on android chrome beta but stopped with the final release, any ideas why this isn't running on android?

**Update:** apologies for the late update, I found out that Omega Rom for some weird reason is messing around with my jquery requests.. switched back and forth couple of times from Omega to stock rom and it was clear that Omega rom was causing weird behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried using $.ajax() instead of $.getJSON()?

Comment: honestly no, I got obsessed with the fact that getjson isn't working and kept googling it and so far no answers :(

Comment: Did you try wrapping that in an actual document.ready function, and not just a self executing function ?

Comment: Have you tried using something other than an `alert()` to display the result? I've seen that be suppressed in some mobile browsers. I don't know about Chrome on Android specifically, but it would be worth double checking.

Comment: tried using    document.write() didn't work also tried using    $(document).ready() that also didn't work

Comment: You do know there's a console you can use in Android as well, and you should probably set the script type ?

Comment: Have you tried giving it an actual function to call as part of the JSONP callback?

Comment: yes I'm aware of that feature however, I cant get it to work because I'm having issues with my usb drivers at the moment.

Comment: @dSquared could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Try copying this entire code and see if it works [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hH3xt/1/), and do remember to copy all of it, especially the last html tag.

Comment: @adeneo just tried that and it didn't work, tried it on stock browser, chrome, FF and htmlviewer

Comment: Well, that works for me, so something else must be the problem?

Comment: @Meldar Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/WeJay/ fiddle. Both this and adeneo fiddle's work on both my Android Tabs and Galaxy Phones. Chances are its something else in your code.

Comment: @dSquared's jsfiddle is working for me on the stock Android browser too, to add a datapoint. I don't have Chrome to test in though.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen I believe its some issue with my phone now, sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help if you remove the self-execution syntax, like this?

```
$.getJSON("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function (data) {
  // Maybe do something like this to display the data more reliably too:
  $(body).append(data.host);
});
```

Comment: Any idea why this helped?